# Apache does not serve non-locally

Tags: fedora, apache-http-server

I have a freshly installed instance of Fedora Core 16 inside VirtualBox using bridged networking.  On it, as root I typed in:

```
yum -y install httpd
service httpd start
ifconfig
```

Inside the VM, I can open a web browser to 'localhost' and I get the Apache test page.  It works.

But in Windows (the machine hosting the VM), I point my browser to the IP address returned by `ifconfig` (192.168.2.122).  The connection times out.  I can go to a command prompt and ping the VM.

Is there a firewall or something that comes with Fedora by default?  Or is there something I need to change in a config file?

Comment: Yes there is a firewall in fedora. Launch `system-config-firewall` so that you can allow http access. Ping and ssh are allowed by default.

Answer (score 0):

```
service iptables stop
chkconfig iptables off
```

The service iptables is the default firewall. Turn it off and then check to make sure it actually is off with chkconfig (sometimes things don't actually die when you tell them to stop) and you can quickly test whether that is what is blocking your connections.

Comment: Would you mind expanding your answer and explaining what that does and why it works? Thank you!